# reading a .ser file into an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am trying to read data from a .ser file and populate an array.

I am getting errors on the last line of the section below for .nextInt() .next() and .nextInt() saying these methods are undefinded for the type ObjectInputStream. I am new to this stuff and I'm assuming I am using the wrong methods to read it in, but I'm not sure what is best...

```
       input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("master.ser"));
       while(count < roster.length) {
           record = (General) input.readObject();  
       roster[count] = new General(input.nextInt(), input.next(), input.nextInt());
       }
```

Comment: ".ser" - this? *A SER file contains a series of frame captures saved in the Lucam video format* `nextInt()` sounds like java.util.Scanner.

Comment: I assume that in this case `.ser` is not Lucam Video Format, but a file produced by an `ObjectOutputStream`. You would need to show us the code that _wrote_ the `.ser` file.  Also, [edit] your post and include the complete stack trace (format as code).